# Design-check; Finding practical accuracy of a DIY voltage-current-temperature meter

Tags: analog, adc, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

### What I plan to do

I'm building a DIY current-voltage-temperature meter. I felt the need for a mV meter, with a good accuracy down to 0.1mV, a mA meter with accuracy down to 1uA and an optional K-type temp sensor. The top range of the measurement for current and voltage is not critical; I'll be fine with a maximum of 5V and 20mA measurement but if it's possible to go higher, why not.

I searched for the available parts (local markets) in the analog block. [ADS1115](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ads1115-q1) precision ADC and [INA180A3](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ina180) (fixed gain of 100x) are what I thought to be suitable for this job. Then the values are read by an I2C microcontroller and shown on a display. For now, I'm concerned with the theoretical accuracy as mentioned by datasheets, not the PCB design (which is a big deal itself.)

Here's the schematic:

[image: ADS1115, INA180 schematic]

### The questions:

Some errors are going tp be corrected in the software. The ADS1115 has an accuracy of ~8uV at its maximum gain. Reading voltages are straight forward; if it's under 5V, I'm going to connect it straight to the ADS and use proper gain settings to read it. Higher values are presented through a divider (software calibrated.) All resistors are 1% and hand-measured for best accuracy.

**Current measurement:**

For the desired 1uA measurement and 7uV accuracy of ADS1115, I calculated the R-sense to 1R. The 1uA current and a gain of 100 of INA180A3 would be `1*100*0.000001 = 100uV` which is about 12 LSBs of ADC. The maximum current would be ~50mA with lowest gain.

Are these results in accordance with real-world values, considering an ideal PCB design? Do I need a protection Zener diode if the current goes up above 50mA? The INA180 has an offset of 0.5mV and 1% gain error.

**Voltage measurement:**

Is this design capable of measuring under 100uV with reliable accuracy?

**Load grounding:**

It seems the GND of the load is shared for measuring current (application designs in datasheets,) but normal multimeters do not need it. They just have two probes and do high-side measurements. What am I missing here?

**Thermocouple:**

I copied the design from another ADC datasheet (ADS1247) because I thought it is somehow a general design. 2.2M resistors make the common voltage and the rest is filtering for differential inputs as quoted by datasheet. Do I have to change them for ADS1115 or for various K-type thermocouples?

**Filtering considerations:**

Is a ferrite-bead/LC filtering needed for a battery powered device?

Comment: _”Is a Ferrite-bead/LC filtering needed for a battery powered device?”_ Most probably not. Have you tried to simulate it with real inductance value of your FB and ESR of the battery?

Comment: *This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.* - I think you may be asking too much in this single question and, you haven't considered drift with ambient temperature.

Comment: Your thermocouple measurement will probably not work. There is no cold junction measurement. And your copied design might rely on the fact that the other ADC has 24 bits of resolution.

Comment: For your voltage/current measurement:

- be careful of the input offset voltage and bias current of your amplifier, as both tend to increase dramatically with common-mode voltage, which it will if you use your design as a high-side current sense. A 500 uV maximum offset voltage, susceptible to change with VCM and temperature when you're looking to amplify a 1 uV difference is not good.

- it doesn't matter for current measurement if the ground is shared with the DUT

- your amplifier will never be able to provide more than 5V (its supply) so no zener needed on the output

Comment: Your themocouple design can be made to work if you measure the temperature at the point where your thermocouple wires change to copper on the board, this is the 'virtual cold junction'. Your resolution will be very poor though. Better would be to use a thermocouple amplifier like an AD8495, or a dedicated thermo to digital solution like MAX31855, both of which have the cold junction compensation built in.

Comment: @Neil_UK I've read that k-type thermocouples' voltage varies about 41uV/C (wikipedia). the lowest measurable voltage mentioned by ADS1115 value is about 7uV. does the screwed terminal block act as a cold junction?

Comment: `does the screwed terminal block act as a cold junction?` yes, so you need to know its temperature